# Show loading image while image loads via jQuery

Tags: jquery, gd

I've got this javascript

```
$(function() {
    $('button').click(function() {         
        $('#imgText').html('&lt;img src="imagecreator.php?param=' + $('input[name=username1]').val() + '"&param="'+ $('input[name=username2]').val() + '" /&gt;');
    });
});​
```

It loads a GD image from an external source, and returns it.
It can be slow, and I can't figure out how to show a loading gif while it loads the external image.

Any input?

Answer (score 0):

Try use some third party stuff, like the one I used often: BlockUI (http://www.malsup.com/jquery/block/), and you just need to block the element which is the container of you image, showing with a customized loading gif, and unblock it in the load event of that image.

EDIT:

A very rough code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/EfGTS/, you need spend some more time play with it to meet you need.

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {
        $('#theContainor').block({ 
            message: '<h1><img src="http://jimpunk.net/Loading/wp-content/uploads/loading45.gif" width="300px" height="300px"/>Just a moment...</h1>', 
            css: { height: '0px'} 
            }); 
        $('#theContainor').append('<img src="http://www.ptb.de/de/aktuelles/archiv/presseinfos/pi2011/bilder/20110228_thoron_big.jpg?seed=' + Math.random() +'" width="300px" onload="$(\'#theContainor\').unblock();"/>');
    });
});​
```